# IPFS connection not working with aragonOSx sdk

Tags: javascript, react, ipfs, goerli

I couldn't get an ipfs connection with aragonOSx SDK (https://github.com/aragon/sdk).

`Error: Could not pin the metadata on IPFS`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is not a traditional IPFS HTTP gateway. We are using a proxied IPFS cluster node.

I assume that you are using the ipfs block uncommented. There is a size limitation, but should not be affecting JSON metadata payloads at all.

Try again using the right dev API KEY (you can reach out to Aragon's discord to get one. They will automate this process in future iterations)